# Sibelius voices/ offset noteheads

Tags: sibelius

How is it possible to offset a note in a second or third voice that shares a stem direction and is more than the interval of a second apart, but that must display each stem separately?

Answer (score 3):

Use flip as necessary to get the stem direction.  Move some of the notes sideways by applying an x-offset in the Inspector.

[image]